# Use caffe to simulate the SGDclassifier or Logisticregression linear models in sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, caffe

I'm trying to use caffe to simulate the SGDclassifier and Logisticregression linear models in sklearn. As we all know, in caffe, one "InnerProduct" layer plus one "Softmaxwithloss" layer represent a logistic regression `Y = Logit(WX+b)`.

I'm now using the digits dataset in the sklearn datasets package as the trianing set(5/6 of all the data-label pairs) and testing set(the rest 1/6). However, the accuracy obtained by `SGDclassifer()` or `LogisticRegression()` could reach nearly 90%, while the accuracy obtained by two-layer Neural Network cannot exceed 30% after training. Is this because of the parameter settings or something else? The gap between them is just kind of too large.